# {I've been reading} vs {I'm reading} (present progressive vs p. perfect progressive)

Tags: present-perfect, present-continuous

I think both

> I'**ve been reading** that book (*lately*)

and

> I'**m reading** that book (*this week*)

are correct. But I struggle to find a difference in meaning. Is there one? Should I avoid one tense or the other?

**EDIT**:
I know how the *present-progressive* is usually used, but it can also be used for [things](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentcontinuous.html) that are **not** currently happening. That's the point of the question.

Answer (score 2):

1. **present perfect continuous**
   for an action that began in the past and continues up to the present.

   > *I'**ve been reading** that book = I started reading it and I don't still finish.*
2. **present continuous**

   - for an action happening now. (Around the present.)

     > *I'**m reading** that book = This is what I'm doing right now.*
   - for something temporarily happening not necessarily at the moment of speaking.

     > *I'**m reading** that book in the evenings.*
   - for arrangements in the future.

     > *I'**m reading** that book next monday.*

Comment: Actually the present-continuous can be used for an activity you are **not** doing right now

Comment: Well ok, but I already knew what tenses they are. I'm asking if there's a difference between the two, and if there is, what's the one preferred

Comment: @drM. Both work for temporary situations. The difference is that *present continuous* doesn't take the action in the past, it takes it on the present. The *present perfect continuous* allows to continue the action that started in the past, or also, to describe the cause of something in the present: *My eyes hurt because I'**ve been reading** that book recently.*

Answer (score 0):

Let's break apart the contractions:

> I've been reading that book (lately)

means

> I **have been reading** that book (lately).

*have been reading* is **present perfect progressive**.  It *emphasizes* that you *have* been performing a continual action at a present time (lately).

> I'm reading that book (this week)

means

> I **am reading** that book (this week).

*am reading* is **present progressive.**  This tense refers to a continual action that is currently occurring ("this week").

**Edit:**

Of the two tenses, **present progressive** tends to be more immediate than **present perfect progressive**.