# I'm reading a book or I've been reading a book? Implying I started some days ago

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, present-continuous, progressive-aspect, present-perfect-progressive

I saw a similar [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/83812/134379), but I'm not content with the answers, i.e. it's still unclear.

It looks like both options are appropriate here, since for **present perfect continuous** can be applied to *an action that began in the past and continues up to the present*; and **present continuous** [can be applied](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/present-continuous-i-am-working) to *temporary states: temporary states which are true around the moment of speaking*, or to *repeated temporary events: actions which are repeated or regular, but which we believe to be temporary*.

So whhich tense to choose? And how circumstances, context can influence the choice?

Comment: Both are correct and idiomatic. It's just a question of where you want to place the emphasis. The present perfect continuous is more likely as an introduction to a sentence such as: I've been reading a book about Winchester that has inspired me to visit the city.

Comment: Got it, thank you!